# How to copy content of element and place it into another element?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

**Example file:**

```
<p>
some content
<a href="1#fn3" class="fn-ref"><sup>3</sup></a>
some content</p>
<p>
some content
<a href="1#fn4" class="fn-ref"><sup>4</sup></a>
some content<a href="1#fn5" class="fn-ref"><sup>5</sup></a></p>
<div class="footnote">
<li id="fn3">
          <p>
            content3 
           <a href="1#fnref3">&#x21A9;</a>
          </p>
        </li>
<li id="fn4">
          <p>
           content4
           <a href="1#fnref4">&#x21A9;</a>
          </p>
        </li>
<li id="fn5">
          <p>
            content5 
           <a href="1#fnref5">&#x21A9;</a>
          </p>
        </li>
<div>
```

I need to place reference footnote at the bottom of the paragraph where the footnote is referenced.(i.e.)if the content in `p`tag has `a`element with class `fn-ref`(one or many `a`tags in a paragraph), I need to place related footnote at the bottom of that paragraph. Related footnote reference can be found in the `div class="footnotes"`

I should search in every `p`tag for `a class="fn-ref"`, If I found, I should create a `div class="footnote"` in which the related footnote reference content should be placed. If it is more than one, then within that `div` element itself reference content should be placed one by one.

**Expected output:**

```
<p>
    some content
    <a href="1#fn3" class="fn-ref"><sup>3</sup></a>
    some content</p>
    <div class=footnote>
       <p>
       <span class="label-fn">
       <a href="1#fnref3" class="ref-fn-ref">3</a>
       </span>
       content3
       </p>
    </div>
    <p>
    some content
    <a href="1#fn4" class="fn-ref"><sup>4</sup></a>
    some content<a href="1#fn5" class="fn-ref"><sup>5</sup></a></p>
    <div class=footnote>
       <p>
       <span class="label-fn">
       <a href="1#fnref4" class="ref-fn-ref">4</a>
       </span>
       content4
       </p>

       <p>
       <span class="label-fn">
       <a href="1#fnref5" class="ref-fn-ref">5</a>
       </span>
       content5
       </p>
    </div>
```

I should try like `parent().clone().html()`  then before and after add stuff but I don't  know where to get started as am newbie in  DOM parser class.

Tried so far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$pElement = $xp->query("//*[contains(@class, "fn-ref")]");

foreach($pElement as $pNode) {
    if ($pNode->nodeName[0] === 'p') {
     //??
```

Comment: Is this using plain Javascript? If so, look into document.querySelectorAll (). You can use it to select all the <p> and then loop through that selection and use it to find all the <a class"fn-ref">

Comment: Am using php  `DOM parser`

Comment: @Learning as Terminus suggests, you could instead do it purely in JavaScript on the client side in the browser, rather than doing it on the server side in PHP.

Comment: Didn't notice you were using php to parse dom (or that it was ecen poaaible. cool!) I'm not too familiar with xpath but if what you have is returning the correct <p> already, in your if statement, do another xpath query for <a> of class fn-ref, if you find footnotes, build your footnote container, loop through xpath result and add footnotes to container, after loop, add container to document. No idea how to do that with DOMDocument object but it should be possible based on the code you're already using.

Comment: I could get a `p` tags where `a class="fn-ref"` resides but I don't know how to get the content of `a` tag from that particular `p` tag. I did `foreach` loop for `p`  tags ,how to search for `a` tag in that loop? How can I get a nodes in `p` loops?

Comment: Use the <p> as the context node. Check out the docs on the `query` function